# Ошибившаяся или ошибшаяся?

Tags: грамотная-речь, словоизменение

Душа, ошибшаяся/ошибившаяся временем.

Как правильнее будет сказать?

Answer (score 1):

Оба варианта допустимы.

Но если первый ("ошибшийся") не вызывает сомнений, то второй ("ошибившийся") дается у Аванесова как  несвободный вариант.
http://slovarina.ru/russkie/slovari/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988_0363.htm

Судя по всему, "ошибшийся" - вариант сравнительно новый, и он активно вытесняет ранее единственно нормативный "ошибившийся".

Answer (score 1):

**В словаре Резниченко (2012) дается только одна форма: ошибившийся.**

В то же время эта форма  вызывает сомнения у носителей языка, например:

―  Позвонил ошибившийся китаец или мошенник? ―  Ошибившийся? Автор сама, похоже, китаянка, и родня звонила. Нет в русском языке слова "ошибившийся", даже комп его подчёркивает.

**Примеры из Нацкорпуса:**

Слова "ошибившийся" нет. Есть два примера:  **Ошибшийся**, спутавший с Чацким Молчалина, в последней сцене, посреди толпы слуг со свечами, Фамусов, обращаясь с упреками к Софии, произносит. [Ю. Н. Тынянов. Сюжет «Горе от ума» (1943) // «Советское искусство», **1945**].

**Также:** "Между прочим, каждый ошибается! А если никогда не давать возможности исправить ошибки, то они так и останутся неисправленными, и **ошибшийся** человек будет этими ошибками жить" (С. Лукьяненко).

**Грамматическая справка**

1) Причастия  образуются **от основы прошедшего времени**: А)  с помощью суффикса ВШ для основ на гласную: писал ―  писавший, отчаяться ―  отчаявшийся, Б) **с помощью  суффикса Ш для основ на согласную:**   нес/ти ―  нёс ―  нёс/ш/ий, расти ―  росший, пасти ―  пасший, везти ―  вёзший, сжечь ―  сжёгший, лечь ―  лёгший.

Тогда: о/шиб/и/ть/ся ― о/шиб/ся ― о/шиб/ш/ий/ся. **И правильной формой должна считаться "ошибшийся".**

2) Интересно, что деепричастие тоже может иметь две формы: **ошибившись и ошибясь**, но здесь "ошибившись" с суффиксом ВШИ является основной и употребляется в речи преимущественно: "Давайте понимать друг друга с полуслова, Чтоб **ошибившись** раз, не ошибиться снова (Б. Окуджава).

**Примеры с суффиксом Я:**

Как его вызволить из этой беды, как жить, чтобы, не ошибясь, не запутавшись, помочь? [Валентин Распутин. Живи и помни (1974)]

В этом случай была сделана одна только ошибка: приятель, желавший меня подвести, слишком понадеялся на мое терпеливое простодушие и, ошибясь в своем расчете, сам попал впросак. [Ф. Ф. Торнау. Воспоминания русского офицера (1874)]

Вот и получается, что **форму "ошибшийся" поддерживает глагольная форма "ошибся", а форму "ошибившийся ― деепричастие "ошибившись".**

Comment: "Интересно, что деепричастие тоже может иметь две формы: ошибившись и ошибясь, но здесь "ошибившись" с суффиксом ВШИ является основной и употребляется в речи преимущественно..." А так ли это? В § 175 «Справочника по правописанию и стилистике» Розенталя сказано: «ошибясь» (не «ошибившись»).

Comment: А как быть с деепр. "ошибшись" (родственно "ошибшемуся"), которое находится во многих книгах? "Ошибившийся" могло образоваться и от глагола "ошибиться" (у инфинитива нет вариантов).

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, что сейчас тенденция в пользу "легитимности" только первого варианта:

T. Гридина, Н. Коновалова, Школьный орфоэпический словарь русского языка, M. 2011
Варианты *ошибшись, ошибшийся* приведены как "**неправ.**"
https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=ASdqAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA253&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&ots=MOR17rtaCy&sig=ACfU3U3xb2haQT5Va9RGqDwwHUOF_BnO5w&w=1280

> ... до недавнего времени не был закреплён "выбор" между... формами
>   *ушибившийся, ошибившийся, ушибив, ошибившись* и формами типа *ушибший, ошибшийся, ушибши, ошибшись*. В последнее время появились **нормативные указания** в пользу форм первого типа (Зализняк 1977,
>   Орфоэпический словарь, 1983).

/Н. Еськова. Избранные работы по русистике. Фонология. Морфонология. Морфология ... М. 2011/
https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=STRqAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA223&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&ots=aIGf4KT2TC&sig=ACfU3U3DJbxNcceFknTjwsDHRKU23etPeg&w=1280